# Animating an UIImageView (View) from Point A to Point B with constraints programmatically

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiviewanimation, nslayoutconstraint

I have an image view that I have lined up on the center right of my screen.  All is fine when adding the image view by itself with constraints.  I need to animate the image view from that original position(Point A) to the bottom portion(Point B) of the screen; the problem is when I try to animate from Point A to Point B, the image view starts off in the upper left hand corner of the screen, like it was simply added with no constraints (as opposed to where I want it starting off in the center) .

Here is the code and some comments:

```
#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(x) (M_PI * x / 180.0) //defined above
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
UIImage *cardFaceDownImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b-top@2x.png"];
UIImageView *dealCardDown = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:cardFaceDownImage];
dealCardDown.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

NSLayoutConstraint *dealCardConstraintY = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:dealCardDown attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1 constant:1];

NSLayoutConstraint *dealCardConstraintX = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:dealCardDown attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1 constant:130];

[self.view addConstraint:dealCardConstraintY];
[self.view addConstraint:dealCardConstraintX];
[self.view addSubview:dealCardDown];

//IF I comment out the below code the UIImageView lines up where I want it (Point A)
//IF I don't coment it out, the imageview starts in the upper left hand corner of the screen
//where it normally would as if just adding an image view programatically without
//constraints would, but it does end up where I want it to (Point B)

[self.view removeConstraint:dealCardConstraintX];
[self.view removeConstraint:dealCardConstraintY];

dealCardConstraintY = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:dealCardDown attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1 constant:1];

dealCardConstraintX = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:dealCardDown attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1 constant:130];

[self.view addConstraint:dealCardConstraintY];
[self.view addConstraint:dealCardConstraintX];

[self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];

[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:2.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn animations:^(void)
 {
     dealCardDown.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(dealCardDown.transform, DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90));

     [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

 }
 completion:^(BOOL finished)
 { 
 }
 ];
 }
```

..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to move change of constraint into animation block, so it will be animated properly.
This code works for me well.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];

UIView *dealCardDown = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){0,0,50,50}];
dealCardDown.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
dealCardDown.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
NSLayoutConstraint *sizeConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: dealCardDown attribute: NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier: 1 constant: 50];
[dealCardDown addConstraint:sizeConstraint];
sizeConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: dealCardDown attribute: NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier: 1 constant: 50];
[dealCardDown addConstraint:sizeConstraint];
[self.view addSubview:dealCardDown];

NSLayoutConstraint *dealCardConstraintX = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:dealCardDown attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.f constant:0.f];
NSLayoutConstraint *dealCardConstraintY = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:dealCardDown attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.f constant:-self.view.center.y+dealCardDown.frame.size.height/2];


[self.view addConstraint:dealCardConstraintX];
[self.view addConstraint:dealCardConstraintY];
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];

[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn animations:^(void)
 {
     dealCardDown.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(dealCardDown.transform, 90*M_PI/180);
     dealCardConstraintY.constant = 0;
     [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished)
 { 
 }
 ];
}
```

Comment: I just copied and pasted in this code.  All it does for me is put a small (50,50) red view on the right hand side of the screen.  The CGAffineTransformRotate works(as it did in my code), and I probably should have left that out of my example, but I need the view to move from the center of the screen to the bottom.  Thank you though!  I appreciate any help.

Comment: Heh wait for a second. It is actually puit it to the right and animate afterward. I will adjust it in a way as you want. Give me a second :)

Comment: It is not starting to animate immediately because you had 2.0 delay in your code example. It also has this odd positioning since you had this 130 offset from center in your example.

Comment: I updated code sample so it moves square from middle to the bottom. Enjoy :)

Comment: new code just has it rotating at the bottom.  I dont see anything animating from point A to point B, just the animation of a the view rotating.

Comment: Hm. I assume something wrong with the whole project setup in your case, since it works perfectly on my end. Here is the whole project - http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3736730/Stackoverflow1.zip It animates red square from the middle to the bottom.

Comment: That Does work!  Why does this work when pressing the button, but doesn't work in the viewDidLoad method though?

Comment: I updated my question with the method, sorry I didn't ask the question right, and VERY much appreciate your time!  I will up vote this answer at least right now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24645/discussion-between-brionh-and-nikita-leonov)

Comment: Just to summarize. It is not working in viewDidLoad because this method called before auto layout applied. To make it work you need to move code to some method that executed further in life cycle, for example - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated